# Go RSA decrypt using public key implementation from java

Tags: java, go, rsa, crypt

Provider has this sample JAVA code to decrypt RSA using public key.

```
 public static byte[] decryptByPublicKey(byte[] encryptedData, String publicKey)
            throws Exception {
        byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(publicKey);
        X509EncodedKeySpec x509KeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        Key publicK = keyFactory.generatePublic(x509KeySpec);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(keyFactory.getAlgorithm());
        
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, publicK);
        int inputLen = encryptedData.length;
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int offSet = 0;
        byte[] cache;
        int i = 0;
        while (inputLen - offSet > 0) {
            if (inputLen - offSet >(2048/8)) {
                cache = cipher.doFinal(encryptedData, offSet,(2048/8));
            } else {
                cache = cipher.doFinal(encryptedData, offSet, inputLen - offSet);
            }
            out.write(cache, 0, cache.length);
            i++;
            offSet = i *(2048/8);
        }
        byte[] decryptedData = out.toByteArray();
        out.close();
        return decryptedData;
    }
```

I have tried to writ the equivalent in Go without any luck.

```
base64DecodeBytesKey, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(os.Getenv("PUBKEY"))
    if err != nil {
        Log(logRef, " error reading  pubkey", err)
    }

    pubKey, err := x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(base64DecodeBytesKey)
c := new(big.Int)
    m := new(big.Int)
    m.SetBytes(data)
    e := big.NewInt(int64(pubKey.E))
    c.Exp(m, e, pubKey.N)
    out := c.Bytes()
    skip := 0
    Log(" payload size:--> ", len(data))
    for i := 2; i < len(out); i++ {
        if i+1 >= len(out) {
            break
        }
        if out[i] == 0xff && out[i+1] == 0 {
            skip = i + 2
            break
        }
    }
    return out[skip:]
```

Above was the first attempt which failed terribly.
`rsa.DecryptPKCS1v15` does require a Private Key which the provider insists it's not necessary.

```
encryptedBlockBytes, err := rsa.DecryptPKCS1v15(
            rand.Reader,
            NO_PRIVATE_KEY_PROVIDED,
            payloadBytes[start:finish])
```

Is there a way to get the decrypted payload from RSA verify PSS using Go crypt library?

Comment: It is not working as you expected. You need private key to decrypt information encrypted by public key. This is how [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) and   [asymmetric encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Public_key_encryption.svg) actually working and invented for. It is nothing about Go lang

Comment: @VictorGubin I get that. But their java sample is said to work.

Comment: if someone calls a function argument like `String publicKey` it doesn't means it is a really public key :) According to the code - is is private. If you have access to original code base follow up the code and look where this argument comes from, I suppose it it some application resource.

Comment: @VictorGubin: In the java code `publicKey` really is a public key, as is clear from the code.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk
Have any idea how the java snippet works under the hood?
@VictorGubin   `keyfactory.generatePublic()`  is not custom function.

Comment: From the Java code the padding is not clear, because only the algorithm is specified, but not the padding. In this case the padding is provider dependent, e.g. PKCS#1 v1.5 for the SunJCE provider.

Comment: @Topaco But how do I implement decrypt on PKCS#1 v1.5 using public key?

Comment: @Topaco
Have any resource links to get me started?

Comment: Please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Java code the padding is not clear, because only the algorithm is specified, but not the padding. In this case the padding is provider dependent, e.g. PKCS#1 v1.5 for the SunJCE provider.

Assuming PKCS#1 v1.5, the combinations `Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE`/private key and `Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE`/public key apply [RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017#section-8.2) as padding. This is functionally identical to signing/verifying with `NonewithRSA` (except that *verifying with `NonewithRSA`* additionally checks the equality of the data compared to *decryption with the public key*).

[`NonewithRSA`](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/6516) means that the data is not hashed and no digest ID is prepended. This algorithm is actually intended to sign already hashed data (after the digest ID has been prepended). It is in no way meant to sign unhashed data, i.e. the Java code misuses this algorithm.
Since the message size is limited with RSA (key size minus the space required by padding), only appropriately short messages can be signed. Unhashed data whose size exceeds the allowed size therefore forces multiple signatures. This is the reason for the multiple decryption in the Java code.
The use of hashed data is not only useful for practical reasons (signing long messages), but also necessary for security reasons, s. e.g. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/6338) and [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/12780).

To implement the functionality of the Java code in Go, a low-level implementation is required for signing/verifying in Go as in the Java code.
Another possibility would be to implement the decryption (m = c^e) and remove the padding yourself, which for RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 simply consists of a sequence of 0xFF values framed by 0x0001 on the left and 0x00 on the right.

In the following, I consider the second approach. The Go code below does the following:

- Import the public key
- Base64 decode the ciphertext
- Split the ciphertext into the individual signature chunks (here 3 chunks containing the same data: *The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog*)
- Decrypt each signature chunk (m = c ^ e)
- Concatenate the decrypted signature chunks

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
    "encoding/pem"
    "crypto/x509"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "encoding/base64"
    "bytes"
    "io"
)

func main() {

    pubKeyPem := `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAoZ67dtUTLxoXnNEzRBFB
mwukEJGC+y69cGgpNbtElQj3m4Aft/7cu9qYbTNguTSnCDt7uovZNb21u1vpZwKH
yVgFEGO4SA8RNnjhJt2D7z8RDMWX3saody7jo9TKlrPABLZGo2o8vadW8Dly/v+I
d0YDheCkVCoCEeUjQ8koXZhTwhYkGPu+vkdiqX5cUaiVTu1uzt591aO5Vw/hV4DI
hFKnOTnYXnpXiwRwtPyYoGTa64yWfi2t0bv99qz0BgDjQjD0civCe8LRXGGhyB1U
1aHjDDGEnulTYJyEqCzNGwBpzEHUjqIOXElFjt55AFGpCHAuyuoXoP3gQvoSj6RC
sQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`

    // Import public key
    pubKey := ImportSPKIPublicKeyPEM(pubKeyPem);    
    // Base64 decode ciphertext
    ciphertextBytes, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString("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")
    // Split ciphertext into signature chunks a 2048/8 bytes and decrypt each chunk
    reader := bytes.NewReader(ciphertextBytes)
    var writer bytes.Buffer
    ciphertextBytesChunk := make([]byte, 2048/8)
    for { 
        n, _ := io.ReadFull(reader, ciphertextBytesChunk)
        if (n == 0) { 
            break
        }
        decryptChunk(ciphertextBytesChunk, &writer, pubKey)
    }
    // Concatenate decrypted signature chunks
    decryptedData := writer.String()
    fmt.Println(decryptedData)      
}

func ImportSPKIPublicKeyPEM(spkiPEM string) (*rsa.PublicKey) {
    body, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(spkiPEM )) 
    publicKey, _ := x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(body.Bytes)
    if publicKey, ok := publicKey.(*rsa.PublicKey); ok {
        return publicKey
    } else {
        return nil
    }   
}

func decryptChunk(ciphertextBytesChunk []byte , writer *bytes.Buffer, pubKey *rsa.PublicKey ){
    // Decrypt each signature chunk
    ciphertextInt := new(big.Int)
    ciphertextInt.SetBytes(ciphertextBytesChunk)
    decryptedPaddedInt := decrypt(new(big.Int), pubKey, ciphertextInt)  
    // Remove padding
    decryptedPaddedBytes := make([]byte, pubKey.Size())
    decryptedPaddedInt.FillBytes(decryptedPaddedBytes)
    start := bytes.Index(decryptedPaddedBytes[1:], []byte{0}) + 1 // // 0001FF...FF00<data>: Find index after 2nd 0x00
    decryptedBytes := decryptedPaddedBytes[start:]  
    // Write decrypted signature chunk
    writer.Write(decryptedBytes)
}

func decrypt(c *big.Int, pub *rsa.PublicKey, m *big.Int) *big.Int {
    // Textbook RSA
    e := big.NewInt(int64(pub.E))
    c.Exp(m, e, pub.N)
    return c
}
```

with the output:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Please note that the code is only an example implementation and in particular does not include exception handling.

---

Test:
The Java code below

```java
String publicKey = "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAoZ67dtUTLxoXnNEzRBFBmwukEJGC+y69cGgpNbtElQj3m4Aft/7cu9qYbTNguTSnCDt7uovZNb21u1vpZwKHyVgFEGO4SA8RNnjhJt2D7z8RDMWX3saody7jo9TKlrPABLZGo2o8vadW8Dly/v+Id0YDheCkVCoCEeUjQ8koXZhTwhYkGPu+vkdiqX5cUaiVTu1uzt591aO5Vw/hV4DIhFKnOTnYXnpXiwRwtPyYoGTa64yWfi2t0bv99qz0BgDjQjD0civCe8LRXGGhyB1U1aHjDDGEnulTYJyEqCzNGwBpzEHUjqIOXElFjt55AFGpCHAuyuoXoP3gQvoSj6RCsQIDAQAB"; 
byte[] ciphertext = Base64.getDecoder().decode("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");
byte[] decrypted = decryptByPublicKey(ciphertext, publicKey); 
System.out.println(new String(decrypted, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

with the method you posted gives the same result.