# How to do rsa multiple decryption in go from this java code

Tags: java, go, encryption, rsa

Provider has this sample JAVA code to decrypt RSA using public key. And doing it by splitting the input into multiple segments. Besides, the rsa Algorithm is not specified clearly.

```java
 public static String Encrypt(String dataStr, String publicKeyStr) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = null;
        String encodedDataStr = null;
        try {
            out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] data = dataStr.getBytes("utf-8");
            String KEY_ALGORITHM = "RSA";
            int MAX_ENCRYPT_BLOCK = 117;
            // get public key
            byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(publicKeyStr);
            X509EncodedKeySpec x509KeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
            Key publicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM).generatePublic(x509KeySpec);
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(keyFactory.getAlgorithm());
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
            int inputLen = data.length;
            int offSet = 0;
            byte[] cache;
            int i = 0;
            // do encryption by multiple iterates
            while (inputLen - offSet > 0) {
                if (inputLen - offSet > MAX_ENCRYPT_BLOCK) {
                    cache = cipher.doFinal(data, offSet, MAX_ENCRYPT_BLOCK);
                } else {
                    cache = cipher.doFinal(data, offSet, inputLen - offSet);
                }
                out.write(cache, 0, cache.length);
                i++;
                offSet = i * MAX_ENCRYPT_BLOCK;
            }
            byte[] encryptedData = out.toByteArray();
            encodedDataStr = Base64.encodeBase64String(encryptedData);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
        return encodedDataStr;
    }
```

below is my translation to go code, but the result is said invalid for them to decode. I assumed that the Algorithm is PKCS1v15.
what is the right way to do it in golang?

```golang
func Encrypt(srcStr string, publicKey *rsa.PublicKey) (string, error) {
    src := []byte(srcStr)
    keySize, srcSize := publicKey.Size(), len(src)
    offSet := 0
    once := 117
    buffer := bytes.Buffer{}
    for offSet < srcSize {
        endIndex := offSet + once
        if endIndex > srcSize {
            endIndex = srcSize
        }
        bytesOnce, err := rsa.EncryptPKCS1v15(rand.Reader, publicKey, src[offSet:endIndex])
        if err != nil {
            return "", err
        }
        buffer.Write(bytesOnce)
        offSet = endIndex
    }
    bytesEncrypt := buffer.Bytes()
    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(bytesEncrypt), nil

}
```

UPDATE: it seems that the java code above uses `RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING`
so the go code above actually works

Comment: I found a similar question, but it is Decryption method, quite like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68984685/go-rsa-decrypt-using-public-key-implementation-from-java

Comment: Please find full examples for RSA encryption with PKCS1.5 padding in this folder (disclaimer: I'm the author): https://github.com/java-crypto/cross_platform_crypto/tree/main/RsaEncryptionPkcs15String

Comment: `Cipher.getInstance("RSA")` will give you the default chaining mode and default padding algorithm, which varies by crypto implementation. Always be explicit about these two things, like in `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING")`

Comment: the java version is actually sdk, what i can do is to translate it into go.Sadly i don't really know well about the rsa Algorithm